# Cipher.doFinal(byte[]) is returning 0 bytes on decryption

Tags: java, encryption

I'm having an issue with javax.crypto.Cipher during decryption. I have created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jsumners/crypto-test/) that demonstrates my problem.

Basically, I'm encrypting a short string of data, "foobar", and then immediately attempting to decrypt it. When the decryption occurs, `cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes)`, the result is 0 decrypted bytes. Clearly I'm missing something here, but I don't see it. Do you see my error? If so, what is it?

Here is the encryption routine:

```
public Optional<EncryptedData> encrypt(String data) {
  Optional<EncryptedData> result = Optional.empty();
  Optional<Cipher> cipherOptional = this.getEncryptCipher();
  if (!cipherOptional.isPresent()) {
    return result;
  }

  Cipher cipher = cipherOptional.get();
  byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
  try {
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal();
  } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    log.error("Bad encryption block size: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
    log.error("Bad encryption padding size: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  }

  if (encryptedBytes != null) {
    Base64.Encoder base64 = Base64.getEncoder();
    EncryptedData encryptedData = new EncryptedData(
      cipher.getIV(),
      encryptedBytes
    );

    result = Optional.of(encryptedData);
  }

  return result;
}
```

And the decryption routine:

```
public Optional<String> decrypt(EncryptedData data) {
  Optional<String> result = Optional.empty();

  Optional<Cipher> cipherOptional = this.getDecryptCipher(data.getIv());
  if (!cipherOptional.isPresent()) {
    return result;
  }

  Cipher cipher = cipherOptional.get();
  byte[] decryptedBytes;
  try {
    decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getData());
    result = (decryptedBytes.length > 0) ?
      Optional.of(new String(decryptedBytes)) : result;
  } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
    log.error("Bad encryption padding size: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    log.error("Bad encryption block size: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  }

  return result;
}
```

Both of which use the following routine to initialize the cipher:

```
private Optional<Cipher> getCipher(int mode, byte[] iv) {
  // where mode is either 1 -> encrypt or 2 -> decrypt
  Optional<Cipher> result = Optional.empty();

  Cipher cipher = null;
  try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(this.algorithmMode);

    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    AlgorithmParameters parameters =
      AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(this.algorithm);
    parameters.init(ivParameterSpec);

    cipher.init(mode, this.key, parameters);
    result = Optional.of(cipher);
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    log.error("Could not find cipher mode: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    log.error("Could not find padding type: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    log.error("Encryption key is invalid: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
    log.error("Algorithm parameter spec invalid: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    log.error("Algorithm parameters invalid: `{}`", e.getMessage());
    log.debug(e.toString());
  }

  return result;
}
```

The error ends up being at [line 38](https://github.com/jsumners/crypto-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/CryptoServiceTest.java#L36) in the actual code.

Comment: I fail to see where, in the encryption routine, you inject data at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I miss something or do you ever supply the actual bytes for encryption. Or do you encrypt 0 bytes?

Don't see any `cypher.update(byte[])` or `cypher.final(byte[])` in the encryption function

Comment: Yep. Like I said, I knew it was going to be totally obvious. I just wasn't able to see it because I was reading what _should_ have been not what actually _was_.

Answer (score -1):

You're not *calling* `Cipher.doFinal(byte[])`. You're calling `Cipher.doFinal()`.

Try doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: Accepting the other answer because it isn't quite as snide.